# Prism.Navigation.INavigationService, is an interface and cannot be constructed

Tags: c#, xamarin, mvvm, prism

i'm getting a strange exception using MVVM Prism.

Here is my code:

LoginPageViewModel.cs file:

```
    using Prism.Commands;
    using Prism.Mvvm;
    using Prism.Navigation;
    using Prism.Services;
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Diagnostics;
    using System.IO;
    using System.Linq;
    using Xamarin.Forms;
    using Prism.Unity;
    using Microsoft.Practices.Unity;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using MobileApp.Views;

    namespace MobileApp.ViewModels
    {
        public class LoginPageViewModel : BindableBase, INavigationAware
        {

            .
            .
            .
            private INavigationService _navigationService;

            public LoginPageViewModel(INavigationService navigationService, ...)
            {
                .
                .
                .
                _navigationService = navigationService;
            }
        }
    }
```

App.xaml.cs file where i call the LoginPage:

```
    using Prism.Unity;
    using MobileApp.Views;
    using Xamarin.Forms;
    using System;
    using System.Globalization;
    using Microsoft.Practices.Unity;
    using Prism.Navigation;
    using Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation;
    using System.Diagnostics;
    using MobileApp.ViewModels;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;

    namespace MobileApp
    {
        public partial class App : PrismApplication
            {
                public App(IPlatformInitializer initializer = null) : base(initializer)
                {

                }

                protected override void OnInitialized()
                {
                    NavigationService.NavigateAsync("LoginPage"); // ERROR here (Exception)
                    .
                    .
                    .
                }

                protected override void RegisterTypes()
                {

                    Container.RegisterTypeForNavigation<NavigationPage>();
                    Container.RegisterTypeForNavigation<LoginPage>();
                    .
                    .
                    .
                }
        }
    }
```

After the NavigationService.NavigateAsync("LoginPage") call, i get this error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: The current type,
>   Prism.Navigation.INavigationService, is an interface and cannot be
>   constructed. Are you missing a type mapping?

Does anyone know how to solve it?
Thank you

Comment: Are you missing a type mapping? I think you're missing a type mapping.  You're missing a type mapping, aren't you? You're missing a type mapping.  Map your types.

Comment: Make sure you are using the ViewModelLocator to set the bindindCOntext and not trying to set it manually in code-behind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you might try making `OnInitialized` async, await the `NavigateAsync` and wrap the whole thing in a try catch with a debug output for any exception.

Second, while what you have here looks correct, this error typically occurs when the Navigation Service has a typo in the name. The way that Unity injects the Navigation Service it has to be named exactly correct or it will not resolve. You might try switching from Unity to DryIoc and see if that resolves your issue. It's also a faster DI container and actually maintained!

Comment: It very odd that parameter name play such critical roule!

Comment: This is a limitation of Unity. DryIoc for example does not have any such limitation.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I tried marking `OnInitialized` as `async` and used `nameof` in `NavigationService.NavigateAsync` to avoid typos, and it didn't work. In case somebody else had the same problem, I solved it when I added this line at the beginning of `RegisterTypes`:

```
Container.Register<Prism.Navigation.INavigationService, Prism.Navigation.PageNavigationService>();
```

It registers `PageNavigationService` as an implementation for `INavigationService`.

Comment: Thanks. I had this problem too, the nav service seemed to not be registered when I tried to use it as a dependency of another service during OnStart, but curiously the NavigationService property did work at that point and it was in the container at that point but wouldn't resolve as a constructor injection for some reason. This fixed that issue.